# Why does JavaScript write nothing on the document (variable) even though there is no null variable

Tags: javascript

I have a website that stores cookies in PHP, and reads them in JavaScript (pure, not jQuery or AJAX). On one page, the code works fine. However, when I test it on my Index page, it shows nothing and shows it in parenthesis where unseeable. CSS don't fix this. HERE'S MY CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
setcookie("username", $_SESSION['username']);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <script>
                function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
                }
                return "";
                };

                var u = getCookie("username");
                var l = "login";
                document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = <?php 
                if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){ echo "document.write(l)"; }
                else { echo "document.write(u)"; };?>;
```

What `if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){}` is, is telling the PHP/JS script(s) that there is not a "logged in" cookie stored. (basically not signed in, hinting `var l = "login"`) Here's what it looks like in Developer Tools (inspect element for my index page.) [image]

While my other working page looks like this.[image]

I'm sure my cookies work, because I check. 
[image]

Please tell me if there is a fix to this. (also before telling me, I know about the

```
function getCookieValue(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';
}
```

code. It doesn't work at all) (NOTE: Running PHP 7.1)

Comment: `document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = <?php 
                if(!isset(...` should be a string so: `... .innerHTML = '<?php ...';`

Comment: still nothing...

Comment: After this line `var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);` can you put `console.log("decodedCookie", decodedCookie);` just to confirm that cookie is available at this point in code. The code otherwise seems quite fine.

Comment: Also, in your console you have an error, what is the error?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Are you setting `username` from any other place in code?

Comment: no not besides $_SESSION['username'] which isn't even linked to JS's cookie. Also, nothing came from `console.log` at all... blank.

Comment: What is $_SESSION["loggedin"] ? I dont think this is JS.

Comment: No, its PHP that I'm crossing over into JS to tell whether to put "Login", or the username of the user. Also, `$_SESSION["loggedin"]` tells my website if a user is logged in or not. If the cookie don't exist, then it says "Login", but if it does, it shows the user's username. I'm using JavaScript to show cookies instead of PHP cuz for some reason PHP echos break my site.

Comment: I can link if necessary. just tell me